# How to retry a request after performing authentication?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm learning `Swift`´s `Combine` by making an app, trying to solve real world use cases.

A common case, I'm performing a request, and the auth token expired. I would like to refresh the token if the request fails with a 401.

Something like:

```
fetchData()
   .flatMap { data, response
      if response.statusCode == 401 {
         refreshToken()
            .fetchData()
      } else {
         Just(data)
      }
   }
   .keepDoingThings()
```

Keep in mind this is just pseudo code.

I have tried a few things indeed, but it's a mess. :)

How can this be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Usually the documentation will tell you in advance when the token expires. Therefore, you should refresh the token before it expires. This will reduce the number of network requests you make.

Answer (score 1):

I tried porting my RxSwift version of this to Combine, but the latter is missing some key operators (`retryWhen` and `flatMapFirst`). One solution, therefore, is to bring RxCombine and RxSwift into your project so you can use my RxSwift solution in your project.

Here's my implementation: https://medium.com/@danielt1263/retrying-a-network-request-despite-having-an-invalid-token-b8b89340d29

RxCombine: https://github.com/freak4pc/RxCombine

RxSwift: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift

I don't expect this answer to be accepted as correct, but it can be a work-around until the necessary operators are added to Combine.

Comment: after you created your custom `retryWhen` operator, did you go around combine-fying the `RetryingTokenNetworkService` gist ? there're some tough points in the gist to convert them into (native) combine equivalent.

Comment: @JAHelia No, I have not. I still have to support 11.4+ so I'm not using Combine yet. That said, the only tough spot is the `flatMapFirst`. Maybe ask how to do that in Combine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tryMap()` to throw Error before `refreshToken`, then do `retry`.

```swift
fetchData()
   .tryMap { data, response in
      if response.statusCode == 401 {
         refreshToken()
            .fetchData()
         throw __MYERROR__.invalidServerResponse
      } else {
         return data
      }
   }
   .retry(3)
   .keepDoingThings()
```